# Unix Submission of R Script Batch Mode

Tags: r, unix

I am trying to run a R Script on a Linux server in Batch mode. The problem is with the last line of the code which throws an error which means that my R script is not going into execution. I tried a lot of variations to run my R script, but it has failed on every occasion. Here is the code

```
#PBS -r n
#PBS -m bea
#PBS -N Maha
#PBS -M r2d2@gmail.com
#PBS -l walltime=3:00:00
#PBS -l procs=1
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
echo "Current working directory is `pwd`"
R=/global/software/R-3.1.0-rh6/bin/R
echo $R
R --vanilla < Maha.R
```

I also tried
    R CMD BATCH Maha.R, source("Maha.R")
Please help with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command `R --vanilla < Maha.R` still looks for `R` on the default path, the fact that you set an environment variable `R=/global/software/R-3.1.0-rh6/bin/R` doesn't change that.

To use that variable, you need to change the command to

```
$R --vanilla < Maha.R
```